# Setting background image makes the button unclickable

Tags: android, android-button

I have created an array of buttons. When I set the background image to each button it becomes unlockable (disabled). Why this happen? Please, anyone, suggest it to me.
My code:

```
LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
    LinearLayout rowLayout=null;
    Button[][] buttons = new Button[6][7]; 

    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);

    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) 
    {
       rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
       rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
       layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            buttons[i][j]=new Button(this);
            buttons[i][j].setText("1");

            buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.but_blue_clicked);
            rowLayout.addView(buttons[i][j],param);
            buttons[i][j].setClickable(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this dynamically? Why not create an XML layout?

Comment: Very strange assignment, hardcoding layouts is not considered the best practice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look below code it helpful to you

```
LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
        LinearLayout rowLayout = null;
        Button[][] buttons = new Button[6][7];

        LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
            layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout, param);
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new Button(this);
                buttons[i][j].setText("1");

                buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_yes);
                rowLayout.addView(buttons[i][j], param);
                buttons[i][j].setClickable(true);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Click Button", 5000).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no code adding listener to button. This is probably the problem.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

very silly mistake.. you forget to add

```
 btnNAme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                //some code

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is good practice to make the `Listener` for array of buttons

```
    for (int ImgBtnID = 0; ImgBtnID <=8; ImgBtnID++) 
            {
                ImgBtnArray[ImgBtnID].setOnClickListener(myListener);
            }


        OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                // @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {//your code
        }
}
```